# Declaring multiples Keys in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

I have an XML file where I need to declare a key for each section.

```
<chapter>
    <section> First section
        <section>Section 1</section>
        <section>Section 2</section>
        <section>Section 3

            <informaltable role="table">
                <thead>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Familly</entry>
                        <entry>Type</entry>
                    </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <row>
                        <entry>F1</entry>
                        <entry>T1</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>F1</entry>
                        <entry>T2</entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>
            </informaltable>
        </section>
    </section>

    <section> Seconde section
        <section>Section 1</section>
        <section>Section 2</section>
        <section>Section 3

            <informaltable role="table">
                <thead>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Familly</entry>
                        <entry>Type</entry>
                    </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <row>
                        <entry>F2</entry>
                        <entry>T2</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>F1</entry>
                        <entry>T2</entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>
            </informaltable>
        </section>
    </section>
</chapter>
```

Now I have the keys defined like so

```
<xsl:key name="byFamilly" match="d:chapter/d:section[1]//d:row" use="d:entry[1]"/>  
<xsl:key name="byFamilly" match="d:chapter/d:section[2]//d:row" use="d:entry[1]"/>
```

In case of number of section >50
It’s possible to declare **one key** continent the different value of each section.

Can any one help me out how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: You say you "need to declare a key for each section". But that's not your requirement, that's your proposed solution to the requirement. You haven't told us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual technique in XSLT 1 is to insert the generated id from the ancestor (i.e. the `section`) in the key value e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="byFamilly" match="d:chapter/d:section//d:row" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::d:section), '|', d:entry[1])"/>
```

In XSLT 2 and later the `key` function has an optional third argument where you could pass in the `section` you want to restrict the lookup to so you wouldn't need to include the id in the key value.